search for files with reader permission in Google drive API if email is not a gmail
I'd like to know if it's possible to query files by permission in drive API only if the permission email is a gmail (and obviously an existing account)
$results = $service->files->listFiles()
with
'myaddress@yahoo.com' in readers

doesn't return result
while
'myaddress@gmail.com' in readers

does
with both addresses present in the permissions array of the files
thanks for any advice, so I don't waste time for something not possible (and I'll have to do it looping all the files in a folder to check for permissions)

is the person running the code owner of the file?

the code is running with a service account (owned by my gmail account in cloud services I use developing)

Have you shared the file with the service account and made it owner.  Remember a service account is not you its like a dummy user.

Interesting behavior, the query only seems to work if the target email address is associated with a google account.
People can bring their own email and create a google account.
So I can register and share files with my outlook.com account. In this case the query does return results.
If the account is not registered in google.com, then I don't get results. We should report this to google.
But to answer your question, yes it's possible if the account happens to be registered at google.
